# How do I change the color of Sublime Text 3 auto-complete with dictionaries (Plist) not CSS?

Tags: sublimetext3

I found the following JSON:

```
{
  "class": "popup_control",
  "layer0.tint": [33, 33, 33],
  "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
  "content_margin": [0, 0]
},

{
  "class": "auto_complete",
  "row_padding": [12, 6],
  "layer0.tint": [33, 33, 33],
  "layer0.opacity": 1.0
},

{
  "class": "auto_complete_label",
  "fg": [176, 190, 197, 255],
  "match_fg": [128, 203, 196, 255],
  "selected_fg": [255, 255, 255, 255],
  "selected_match_fg": [128, 203, 196, 255]
},

{
  "class": "table_row",
  "layer0.tint": [97, 97, 97],
  "layer0.opacity": 0.0,
},
```

how do I convert that to plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you posted above isn't CSS, it's JSON. Due to the terminology used, it's very common to mistake the following two things:

- A `theme`, which is used to style the UI in Sublime Text, such as the color and shape of the tabs, as well as fonts used and so on. These are stored in a `sublime-theme` file, which is JSON (not CSS as your question mentions).
- A `color scheme`, which is used to provide the colors used for syntax highlighting. It's stored in a `tmTheme` file, which is a PList (XML) file, a format borrowed from TextMate.

As a result, it's not possible to style what you want to style using the PList format; you're stuck with the JSON format.

However, the question title and the question body are asking separate questions. For the sake of completeness, the answer to the question "how can I turn this JSON into a PList" is to use a dedicated tool for this purpose, such as [this one](http://json2plist.sinaapp.com/) (first hit in google), even though in this case that is of purely academic interest only.

Note however that the JSON posted in your question isn't strictly JSON compliant; It is the body of an array, and there is a trailing comma after the `"layer0.opacity": 0.0` portion of the last object.

In the first case you need to wrap the entire content with square braces `[` and `]` and in the second case you need to remove the trailing comma.

Sublime itself is not sensitive to trailing commas in JSON; it has a more lax parser that allows them as well as comments without throwing an error.